# Uploading to S3 gives 403 Forbidden when specifying Server-Side-Encryption (SSE)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, meteor, encryption, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to S3 from my meteor app, such that the data is encrypted at rest. I'm using [this package](https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3), but I modified it because it doesn't yet support specifying SSE (I created this [issue](https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3/issues/130) for it).

In my forked version of the code, I added these lines to the `uploadFile` function near the bottom of [this file](https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3/blob/master/client/functions.coffee):

```
if ops.server_side_encryption
    form_data.append "x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256"
```

and a way to set `ops.server_side_encryption` to true.

This is all very simple, and I successfully add `x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"` to the form_data that gets posted. The problem is that adding this parameter causes a 403 Forbidden response from s3.

[AWS docs don't say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) that the bucket needs to be anything special to *allow* this new parameter, and thus SSE. They talk about *enforcing* that a client request specifies encryption, and I also tried adding that policy to no avail (though I wouldn't expect that to work because the docs don't say you need a special policy to allow this parameter).

Is there missing info, about some configuration that needs to be in place to allow that SSE parameters in client upload requests?

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a custom policy on the S3 bucket that is preventing AES256 encryption from being used?

Comment: I'd say no, because the policy is blank, and I played around with _adding_ a policy, which successfully disallowed requests that DIDN'T specify SSE, but could not successfully allow requests that specify SSE.

Comment: If you comment out the above code then you are able to upload without any issues (other than the file being unencrypted)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the form POST method of uploading a file to S3, but it looks like it requires a policy document in the post that can contain certain restrictions. I'd check the policy document being sent to see if it needs to allow encryption.

Comment: You nailed it... Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (which I found thanks to Mark B's comment) is this:

I was using the form POST method of uploading a file to S3. I forgot that the policy document in the post can contain certain restrictions. The policy document being sent needed to allow encryption (`{"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"}` as one of my conditions).